# Cannot connect to cassandra through pycharm python console, but can connect via python in a terminal

Tags: python-2.7, pycharm, cassandra-2.0

I am trying to connect to the cassandra 2.1.5 using the latest python driver. It works like a charm if I run python on a terminal, or if I run a python code from pycharm.

```
from cassandra.cluster import Cluster;
k = Cluster();
k.connect('mykeyspace');
```

However, if I try to do it from python console inside pycharm (or If I use debug mode and step through the code), the last line:

```
k.connect('mykeyspace');
```

Throws me an operation timedout error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/rajee/workspace/bemoss_os/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/cassandra/cluster.py", line 755, in connect
    self.control_connection.connect()
  File "/home/rajee/workspace/bemoss_os/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/cassandra/cluster.py", line 1868, in connect
    self._set_new_connection(self._reconnect_internal())
  File "/home/rajee/workspace/bemoss_os/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/cassandra/cluster.py", line 1903, in _reconnect_internal
    raise NoHostAvailable("Unable to connect to any servers", errors)
NoHostAvailable: ('Unable to connect to any servers', {'127.0.0.1': OperationTimedOut('errors=None, last_host=None',)})
```

So, Why can't I connect to the Cassandra server via python-console (and the debugger?). Looks like something got to do with ports, but I don't know exactly how the debugger and the console works.
To repeat, I can connect to the server via python ran in terminal.

Any Solutions?

Further Infos:
The python console is run as follows:
[image]

The python debugger is run as follows:
[image]

Thank you.

Comment: I tried changing the listening address and rpc address on the cassandra.yaml file to my ip address (instead of localhost). Doing this I can connect to the cassandra server via cqlsh on any computer in the network, or through cassandra-python driver on any python console on the network. However, the pycharm python console and the pycharm debugger still cannot connect to the server. Weired!

Comment: Hi, As I dug in, I found a workaround suggested here: https://groups.google.com/a/lists.datastax.com/forum/#!topic/python-driver-user/jG1kt_DuJko
The solution is to specify connection class during cluster intialization, like this:
`from cassandra.io.libevreactor import LibevConnection`  `session = Cluster(connection_class=LibevConnection).connect()`
This involves having to have libevreactor installed properly, which requires installation of C-extension before installing cassandra driver. See the documentation for cassandra driver installation.